# Laravel and blade error still not solved

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I just wanted to show the image by

```
<img src="{!!DB::table('users')->where('username',$game->initiator)->first()->photo_path!!}" alt="" />
```

but i get a error

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

I have tried all of the methods like removing brackets, quotes and using `Html::image` but no cure was found.

But when I change my code to

```
{!!dd(DB::table('users')->where('username',$game->initiator)->first()->photo_path)!!}
```

or

```
{{dd(DB::table('users')->where('username',$game->initiator)->first()->photo_path)}}
```

I get a url of gravatar which is set in the database and this url has double quotes like :- `"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5478144dd02f370affc2ad70f22af697?s=200&r=pg&d=identicon"`

which means that the link exists in database but why error is showed up.
I tried

```
<img src="{!!url(DB::table('users')->where('username',$game->initiator)->first()->photo_path)!!}" alt="" />
```

but this too didn't work for me.

Also when I just replace `$game->initiator` by a username, then image is displayed correctly. Those who think the variable `$game->initiator` is empty then they are wrong, I used `dd()` function to see whether it is empty or not and then I found it contains a user details.

I cannot do this thing in the controller because I have more than 1000 games and all have a initiator and a acceptor whose images are to be displayed.

EDIT : When I add `{{dd($game)}}` after the image then it worked and suppressed the error but the error is still view-able from the source of the html
It looks like

```
<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, idRx = /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[012]\w+\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') ? 'Cmd' : 'Ctrl', addEventListener = function (e, n, cb) { e.addEventListener(n, cb, false); }; (doc.documentElement.firstElementChild || doc.documentElement.children[0]).appendChild(refStyle); if (!doc.addEventListener) { addEventListener = function (element, eventName, callback) { element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, function (e) { e.preventDefault = function () {e.returnValue = false;}; e.target = e.srcElement; callback(e); }); }; } function toggle(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className, arrow, newClass; if ('sf-dump-compact' == oldClass) { arrow = '&#9660;'; newClass = 'sf-dump-expanded'; } else if ('sf-dump-expanded' == oldClass) { arrow = '&#9654;'; newClass = 'sf-dump-compact'; } else { return false; } a.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; s.className = newClass; if (recursive) { try { a = s.querySelectorAll('.'+oldClass); for (s = 0; s < a.length; ++s) { if (a[s].className !== newClass) { a[s].className = newClass; a[s].previousSibling.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; } } } catch (e) { } } return true; }; return function (root) { root = doc.getElementById(root); function a(e, f) { addEventListener(root, e, function (e) { if ('A' == e.target.tagName) { f(e.target, e); } else if ('A' == e.target.parentNode.tagName) { f(e.target.parentNode, e); } }); }; function isCtrlKey(e) { return e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey; } addEventListener(root, 'mouseover', function (e) { if ('' != refStyle.innerHTML) { refStyle.innerHTML = ''; } }); a('mouseover', function (a) { if (a = idRx.exec(a.className)) { try { refStyle.innerHTML = 'pre.sf-dump .'+a[0]+'{background-color: #B729D9; color: #FFF !important; border-radius: 2px}'; } catch (e) { } } }); a('click', function (a, e) { if (/\bsf-dump-toggle\b/.test(a.className)) { e.preventDefault(); if (!toggle(a, isCtrlKey(e))) { var r = doc.getElementById(a.getAttribute('href').substr(1)), s = r.previousSibling, f = r.parentNode, t = a.parentNode; t.replaceChild(r, a); f.replaceChild(a, s); t.insertBefore(s, r); f = f.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); t = t.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); if (f && t && f[0] !== t[0]) { r.innerHTML = r.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('^'+f[0].replace(rxEsc, '\\$1'), 'mg'), t[0]); } if ('sf-dump-compact' == r.className) { toggle(s, isCtrlKey(e)); } } if (doc.getSelection) { try { doc.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); } catch (e) { doc.getSelection().empty(); } } else { doc.selection.empty(); } } }); var indentRx = new RegExp('^('+(root.getAttribute('data-indent-pad') || ' ').replace(rxEsc, '\\$1')+')+', 'm'), elt = root.getElementsByTagName('A'), len = elt.length, i = 0, t = []; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); elt = root.getElementsByTagName('SAMP'); len = elt.length; i = 0; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); root = t; len = t.length; i = t = 0; while (i < len) { elt = root[i]; if ("SAMP" == elt.tagName) { elt.className = "sf-dump-expanded"; a = elt.previousSibling || {}; if ('A' != a.tagName) { a = doc.createElement('A'); a.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; elt.parentNode.insertBefore(a, elt); } else { a.innerHTML += ' '; } a.title = (a.title ? a.title+'\n[' : '[')+keyHint+'+click] Expand all children'; a.innerHTML += '<span>&#9660;</span>'; a.className += ' sf-dump-toggle'; if ('sf-dump' != elt.parentNode.className) { toggle(a); } } else if ("sf-dump-ref" == elt.className && (a = elt.getAttribute('href'))) { a = a.substr(1); elt.className += ' '+a; if (/[\[{]$/.test(elt.previousSibling.nodeValue)) { a = a != elt.nextSibling.id && doc.getElementById(a); try { t = a.nextSibling; elt.appendChild(a); t.parentNode.insertBefore(a, t); if (/^[@#]/.test(elt.innerHTML)) { elt.innerHTML += ' <span>&#9654;</span>'; } else { elt.innerHTML = '<span>&#9654;</span>'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } elt.className += ' sf-dump-toggle'; } catch (e) { if ('&' == elt.innerHTML.charAt(0)) { elt.innerHTML = '&hellip;'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } } } } ++i; } }; })(document); </script>
```

Comment: The error is not in this line but somewhere else in your iew, check the stacktrace and get the line number.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you exactly what’s wrong: **you’re trying to get a property of non-object.**

Because you’re method-chaining (`DB::table('users')->where('username',$game->initiator)->first()->photo_path`) it’s difficult to see *exactly* where the issue is, so you need to step through each method call and find out where it’s failing (it’ll return `null` rather than an object).

So in your code, start stepping through the methods…

```
dd(DB::table('users'));
dd(DB::table('users')->where('username', $game->initiator));
```

…and so on, until you find out which method returns `null` rather than an object.

Comment: When I use `dd`, no error occur but if dont use `dd` the error occurs and i cannot use `dd` in image source

Comment: When simply using `{{dd(DB::table('users')->where('username',$game->initiator)->first()->photo_path)}}` I get no error

Answer (score 0):

Facades are supposed to live in global namespace. Try to use:

```
{{ \DB::table('users')->where('username', $game->initiator)->first()->photo_path }}
```

If it doesn't, your alias is not registering properly. Check config/app.php > `aliases` and make sure **DB** is listed there.

Comment: I checked my config/app.php and found DB listed there and using a `\` doesn't help too

Comment: and if `DB` was not listed in aliases, how would the dd command containing the query work?

Answer (score 0):

The real problem arised because I have made some changes in the users table . I changes the datatype of `balance` from `string` to `bigint` and after that change I was getting the above errors.

You should also check if this had happened to you.

Solution : You should change the column from migration file or create another database or dump the values in that table.

In my case I changed the database.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. 
with DB you get access to a record in database, but it is not an instance of a Model.
Try to access the data by a model, in your case just use `\App\User::where(....` and see if the error occures.